# How to fix Realm warning Invalid Source (file not found primitive_list_notifier.cpp)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm, xcode13

When I built an iOS project using Realm (5.5.2) on Xcode 13, I have the following warning concerning Realm.

> realm-cocoa (Uncategorized)
> Invalid Source
> '/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/demo-gehwjphdwijztlgvgfwikjdkhvzb/SourcePackages/checkouts/realm-cocoa/Realm/ObjectStore/src/impl/primitive_list_notifier.cpp':
> File not found.

I do not understand this warning. Does it have an impact on the project and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue in Realm swift, there were tickets opened for this.

https://github.com/realm/realm-swift/issues/7393

One of the maintainers said it should be fixed in the next release but v5 of Realm is on a slower release cycle compared to v10.

I also noticed that the issue posted on GitHub mentioned it could be due to Swift Package Manager.

I don't think it should impact the project, however, solutions that should work include:

- Upgrading Realm to 10.8.1 or greater
- Using Xcode 12.5 since the release notes for Realm 5.5.2 mention it was built in Xcode 12.5
- Use Cocoapods instead in the case you were using Swift Package Manager

Release Notes for Realm Swift 5.5.2: https://github.com/realm/realm-swift/releases/tag/v5.5.2

Comment: Great answer! I would like to add the issue was resolved and closed from 10.8.1 and after - however, if you go to a later version there were a number of underlying changes and your Realm files will need to be upgraded - which then breaks backward compatibility. So, upgrade the SDK, update the Realm Files and then you'll also need a newer version of Realm Studio.